# Prevent browser caching with an ASP.NET OutputCacheProvider

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

I'm using a System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheProvider.  I do not want browsers to cache, I only want to do server caching.  I see that when something comes out of my server cache, they get an Expires header of 24 hours in the future.  How do I modify this?

Calling HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires() in my Get() method doesn't have an effect and neither does changing HTTP Response Headers->Set Common Headers->Expire Web content in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Location attribute for OutputCache attribute. For Asp.Net Web Pages

`<%@ OutputCache Location="Server" ...%>`

For Asp.Net MVC

`[OutputCache(Location=OutputCacheLocation.Server)]`

After that the classic `Response.Expires = 0` approach should be enough (if necessary) to prevent browser caching.